# Why does the /locate command in minecraft not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using Minecraft Java, 20w19a, a snapshot of the new 1.16 update. Whenever I type in `/locate Pillager_Outpost` or `/locate Mansion`, nothing happens. No text appears anywhere, nothing about finding the structure. I typed `/locate` multiple times, using random structures that I knew should generate. However, each time, nothing came to the chat box. I also tried updating to 1.16 Pre-Release2

Comment: Does the server keep ticking? Does the bottom right Alt+F3 graph move?

Comment: If you're playing on a recent snapshot, it could be likely that the locate command could be broken on that particular snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

I had turned off the "Send command Feedback" gamerule, causing the `/locate` command to not send the feedback to chat.

Comment: I didn't know I had turned it off when I was actually playing. I have bad memory for certain game rules.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `/locate` can take a while to return a result, especially if your structure is a while away. Be patient, and if it doesn't return anything after about a minute or so, there may be a different problem.

The longest it took for me to get a result is about 10 seconds.

If a structure is not found, it should return red text, `Could not find that structure nearby.` If you are not getting any output, it could be a different problem.

As of today, the current Minecraft version is 1.16-pre2. Consider updating, and this bug may have been fixedl

Comment: according to the wikipedia, that's for a newer snapshot. when I type it, those 2 also aren't valid for my version's commands.

Comment: after testing how long it took for a ```/locate Pillager_Outpost```, I have concluded that there is a different problem. The first command typed never returned after a counted minute that I spent counting and jumping around on Minecraft trees.

Comment: other times that I've used the command, like in other Minecraft java worlds, they always returned after at least 5 seconds. this comment is just to supply a bit of information.

Comment: I'm not getting any output. But after some research, I entered another world in the same version, with an obvious village next to it, typed ```/locate Village```, and got no output.

Comment: no, updating did not work. It took more than a minute, and I still got no output. Does it not say that the structure couldn't be found, or is this truly a bug?

Comment: If you get no response at all, ensure that you have not changed the "sendcommandfeedback" gamerule to false (not sure if this exists in Java, as I play bedrock edition, but this is usually what causes this problem in bedrock...) -edit: if the same problem occurs in multiple worlds, then this probably is not the cause of the issue...

Comment: It does exist in java, I think I have turned that off in multiple worlds.